# Sending AppController to parameter of incompatible type

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chartboost

I'm implementing Chartboost into a cocos2d app and I'm receiving the following error:

```
Sending 'AppController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<ChartboostDelegate>'
```

The code is taken from the Chartboost documentation like this:

```
[Chartboost startWithAppId:@"App ID" appSignature:@"App Signature" delegate:self];
```

Not sure what I am missing, maybe an import? I have "Chartboost.h" integrated and I follow the documentation exactly as it is written. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `AppController` doesn't conform to the `ChartboostDelegate` protocol; i.e.:

```
@interface AppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate, ChartboostDelegate>
```